# Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate the definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate the definite integral

$\displaystyle\int_0^3 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}dx$

I dont get what they want here is it just to take the $F'(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ where $x$ is $0$ and $3$ and find the mid point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: check that

$$\left(2\sqrt{1+x}\right)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$$

Comment: So it would end up F(b)-F(a) = -4--2 = -2?? my book tells me it should be 2 :(

Comment: His Integrand is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$, not what you have written.

Comment: Someone edited it after i posted so i just put it back sorry

Comment: He did what!! My apologies if this is the case. In the original integrand, the integrand is not defined from 1 to 3. Now it is fine.

Comment: sorry someone edited it its all right now sorry for the time wasting

Comment: well i am sorry did not pick up on it my bad :(

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for the time wasting i will try harder from now on to get it right .

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that, if $F'(x) = f(x)$, then

$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = F(b) - F(a)$$

That is, evaluate $F$ at the endpoints.

Comment: So it would end up F(b)-F(a) = -4--2 = -2?? my book tells me it should be 2 :(